# PyCharm: Shadows built in name 'self', bug or feature?

Tags: python, class, pycharm, ironpython, self

I'm using PyCharm IDE; I love it for all the work it does for me. I found it very powerful in my process of learning python. It has all the hints about variables names, typos etc...

However now I'm a little bit confused. When using PyCharm with IronPython 2.7, Pycharm is throwing me an info while class methods definition.

```
Shadows built-in name 'self'
```

In my opinion everything is ok with that class:

```
class A(object):
    """
    Cheers Stackoverflowers
    """
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x + 2

    def calculate_something(self, y):
        self.x = y * 2
```

But I would like to be 100% correct while programming. And if there are more correct ways to define method in class definition I would like to know where I can find information about that.

Screenshot:

[image: Pycharm screenshot showing error]

Comment: Isn't it just an indentation problem? Your methods should be indented after you defined the class.

Comment: Your code is correct. Which version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: Pycharm Community edition 4.0.4

Comment: It's not indication problem for sure :)

Comment: I get an `IndentationError: expected an indented block` when I use the exact same code you posted. Even with indenting it i am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tomasz: there *was* such a problem *here*; please use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format code blocks; I corrected your indentation for you.

Comment: @d6bels: it is *very common* for new users to just indent the first line when trying to format code. It 'fixes' the formatting problems they see when first posting... The number of times I have *un*indented the first line, then selected the whole code block and then indented the whole block again..

Comment: And which Python version are you using? I don't seem to be able to reproduce this problem in PyCharm 4.0.4.

Comment: @yole - That's may be the problem - I'm using latest **IronPython 2.7**

Comment: @Tomasz: That is important information; added that in for you.

Comment: thanks @yole . Also thanks for testing. Now i know it is a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a IronPython Bug

It does not happen while using CPython

Thanks @yole